# Redux Form resubmission after error

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Is it possible to resubmit form after submission error?

I have a form similar to the one in the example.

http://redux-form.com/6.0.2/examples/submitValidation/

I also return the common _error. And everything works well. But I can't resubmit the form again without changing the inputs. 
What if I want to allow users to resubmit the form again without changing the inputs in case if it is a temporary server error?

Comment: Is [this issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1641) related?  It looks like a regression they've only noticed in the last few days.

Comment: This is another issue. It was related to the bug that when you submit after error with changed (correct) input the error remained. In my case I don't want to change any inputs I  just want to submit form once again after error.